# How do I do a grab in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've seen medals awarded for successfully completing a grab in ME3 multiplayer. So what is a grab and how do I do one?

Comment: Probably melee range, although could be biotic.  My guess would be one of the heavy melee attacks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are in cover, and an enemy is in the other side of the cover, you will see a blue fist. Hit your melee button, and you will reach over, grab the guy, pull him to your side, and then kill him. This is the grab medals are awarded for.

They are difficult to pull off because enemies will run away if they see you enter cover opposite them.

Comment: Neat! I'll have to try this.

Comment: Same thing as a heavy Melee while in cover. Infiltrators have an easier time because they can cloak and run in. For non-infiltrators I recommend Geth Pyros for practice as they'll just walk up to the cover heedless of their imminent death. Sometime you can get lucky and get a Geth Hunter with the same stupidity.

Comment: I've seen someone do 5 grabs in quick succession on Gold Geth; I think the AI was too busy focusing on targeting one of the other players; stupid AI! :-) Good fun.

Comment: I'm assuming that was the in the bottom room in Firebase White? The enemy AI is notoriously bad at handling a team setup there. So much, that GWG (Geth White Gold) became the goto strategy for farming credits.