# Is the grab animation the same for all races and classes?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is the grab animation the same for all races and classes in Mass Effect 3? I have heard rumors that Krogan grab animation doesn't use the Omniblade.

P.S For those we don't know how to grab: "[How do I do a grab in ME3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/51588/1770)"

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: For me, I find questions about "What do the graphics look like in scenario X?" to be not useful.  YMMV.

Comment: +1 the graphic is a huge part of the game and matters. at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the grab animations vary from race to race. Quarian, Turian, and Human have a similar animation. Asari and Drell has a biotic flair and Krogan simply punches the enemy. This is shown in this YouTube video: